# Remove duplicates from an array of objects based on the first 3 words of object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this array of objects which have a lot of duplicate entries. I can clean the array and get rid of the duplicate ones but the catch is I need to remove those which matches based on the property's first 3 words.

Suppose this is the array:

```
let arr = [
     {
         text: "Be good and you will be lonely. But there’s nothing wrong with being lonely.",
         id: 1
     },
     {
         text: "Coffee is a way of stealing time.",
         id: 2
     },
     {
         text: "Be good and you will be lonely. But there’s nothing wrong with being lonely.",
         id: 3
     }
];
```

I want to match the first 3 words of each of the texts and if it is a match then remove one of the matched objects from the old array and push the removed one to a new array.

So far I could remove the duplicate ones with this piece of code and I don't know what I should do next.

```
let texts     = {};

arr = arr.filter(function(currentObject) {
      if (currentObject.text in seenNames) {
           return false;
      } else {
           seenNames[currentObject.text] = true;
           return true;
      }
});
```

It would be a big help if someone point me to the right direction.

UPDATE:

I started the whole thing again with a different approach than before. As @Andreas and @freedomn-m said, I split the items based on the first 3 words and then tried to filter the original array by matching the split items. But right now I'm getting all the values back without any filtration.

```js
let arr = [{
    "text": "Be good and you will be lonely. But there’s nothing wrong with being lonely.",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "text": "Coffee is a way of stealing time.",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "text": "Be good and you will be lonely. But there’s nothing wrong with being lonely.",
    "id": 3
  }
];

let removedItems = [];


let filtered = arr.filter((item, index) => {
  let splitItem = item["text"].split(" ").slice(0, 3).join(" ").toLowerCase();

  if (item["text"].toLowerCase().startsWith(splitItem, index + 1)) {
    return item;
  } else {
    removedItems.push(item);
  }

});



console.log(filtered);
console.log(removedItems);
```

Comment: So find a way to get the _"first three words"_. Is there an obvious separator you could work with (like splitting the string at that separator)... What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: @Andreas no there's no obvious separator. They are just simple pieces of texts. And no I could only remove the duplicate ones. Like exact match duplicates.

Comment: "Coffee" is a word, "is" is a word, ... There's no "Coffeeis" so something has to separate them...

Comment: The data is dynamic. It depends totally on the user what the text will be. May be separate them with the first three spaces?

Comment: Now you're getting it...

Comment: @freedomn-m Lol. Don't know what to do next. Help me please.

Comment: Try these: [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)  [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: `var words = currentObject.text.split(" ").slice(0,3).join(" ")`  (might be more efficient with a regex/nested indexOf for very long sentences)

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes. Check the OP. I tried something based on your code.

Comment: You can *add* your updated attempt, then we'll have a look.  Make sure you replace both cases of `currentObject.text` with `words`

Comment: @freedomn-m Oopps. Sorry I forgot to add it. Btw, I tried it with a different approach than before.

Comment: When you use `.filter(func())` you need to return a bool from the func to determine which ones are included/excluded.   This code `item["text"].toLowerCase().startsWith(splitItem)` will always be true, because `splitItem` is rebuilt from `item.text` each time.  Your original code would work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the original question of how to get 3 words, one option is to use
.split() .slice() and .join():

```
var firstWords = item["text"].split(" ").slice(0, 3).join(" ");
```

you can then do a straight replacement of `currentObject.text` with `firstWords`, from the original question:

```
let texts = {};
arr = arr.filter(function(currentObject) {
    if (firstWords in seenNames) {
         return false;
    } else {
         seenNames[firstWords] = true;
         return true;
    }
});
```

The update attempts this, but has 2 issues:

- `.filter(function(item))` must return true/false (as it did originally) not the `item`/nothing.
- `item["text"].toLowerCase().startsWith(splitItem)` will always be true as splitItem is built from item["text"]

Adding the `removedItems` additional list to the original gives:

```js
let arr = [{
    "text": "Be good and you will be lonely. But there’s nothing wrong with being lonely.",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "text": "Coffee is a way of stealing time.",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "text": "Be good and you will be lonely. But there’s nothing wrong with being lonely.",
    "id": 3
  }
];

let removedItems = [];
let seenNames = {};

let filtered = arr.filter((item, index) => {
  let splitItem = item["text"].split(" ").slice(0, 3).join(" ").toLowerCase();
  
  if (splitItem in seenNames) {
    // already exists, so don't include in filtered, but do add to removed
    removedItems.push(item);
    return false;
  }
   
  // doesn't exist, so add to seen list and include in filtered
  seenNames[splitItem] = true;
  return true;
});

console.log(filtered);
console.log(removedItems);
```